# where is visual studio code command line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I searched full day but could not find answer.

Wherever I search for how to install visual studio code from .visix it says.

> If your extension is packaged with .vsix file, you can install it from
>   command prompt using this command

But where is this command prompt? Where I will write this command?

```
code <extensionfolder>\<extensionpackagename>.vsix
```

I tried running it in command prompt but gave code is not a command.

I added code.exe to path but still when I run command it says visual studio code could not open this file as being unsupported.

there is nothing like integrated terminal option in my visual studio code.

[image]

command pallete is not working either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the **Integrated Terminal**.

**View -> Intergrated Terminal** is where you will find it.

I also believe [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/install-extension#_install-a-packaged-extension-vsix) will be useful for what you are trying to accomplish.

After installing to the newest version of Visual Studio Code, you will see a Extensions Menu where you can install extensions from and also Integrated Terminal will appear in your View menu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject, I think you are using an older version of Visual Studio Code. I don't see the Extensions icon on your sidebar either, so updating to the newest version of Visual Studio Code should fix your problem.
After installing the newest version of Visual Studio Code, you can install extensions from Extensions(CTRL+Shift+X) menu that was added recently, so you won't even have to write that command in the Integrated Terminal.